# How to convert output with hexadecimal data to unicode?

Tags: bash, hex

I have file with hex symbols like below

```
cat demo 
\x22count\x22
\x22count\x22
\x22count\x22
```

I need conversion like:

```
echo $(cat demo)
"count" "count" "count"
```

How to get unicode symbols in pipeline with newline symbol? Something like:

```
cat demo | ???

"count" 
"count" 
"count"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf`'s `%b` conversion specification. This will print the output you want:

```
printf '%b\n' "$(<demo)"
```

Note: `%b` causes `printf` to expand other backslash escape sequences as well (e.g., `\n`, `\t` etc.)

Comment: thanks, it works! Could you please advise, how to use it with pipe? Something like `cat /tmp/ssv_count | xargs -I{}  printf '%b\n' {}`  . My command returns x22countx22 three times

Comment: @gayavat `xargs` is error-prone and rarely useful in a `bash` script. You shouldn't use it unless you have to. But if you _really_ insist, this should work for GNU `xargs` : `cat /tmp/ssv_count | xargs -d '\n' -I{}  printf '%b\n' {}` . (`-d` option is not specified in the POSIX standard, but is implemented by GNU systems).

Comment: Excellent! thanks a lot! Is it any alternative of xargs? if i need use printf in the middle of pipeline? I.e something like 
`cat demo |   xargs -d '\n' -I{}  printf '%b\n' {} | grep count > result`

Comment: @gayavat `printf '%b\n' "$(<demo)" | grep count > result` if you want to `grep` _after_ the `%b` conversion, or, `printf '%b\n' "$(grep count demo)" > result` if you want to `grep` _before_ the `%b` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use printf to convert the hexadecimal data.
Depending on the size of your input, you could read the lines into an array
then use IFS to delimit the output:

```bash
join() {
    local IFS="$1"
    shift
    echo "$*"
}
```

```bash
arr=( $(while read -r line; do printf "$line "; done < demo) )

join $' ' "${arr[@]}"
"count" "count" "count"

join $'\n' "${arr[@]}"
"count"
"count"
"count"
```

Comment: Yes, `printf` can be used for this purpose, but the way it is used in this answer is incorrect. `printf`'s format string shouldn't come from user input (unless the input is supposed to be a format string): It won't produce correct output if the input contains format specifications (eg, `%s`, `%d`, etc.).